# How to transfer a phrase from an assistant to the my app

Tags: android, app-actions

Please tell me how to open your application through Google Assistant and transfer the phrase that the user said to it?
Example:
User: "Open the barrier number 12 in the (application name)"
Then, the application opens and an action with the phrase "barrier number 12" is transmitted to MainActivity, after which the application launches what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

To extend your Android App to the Assistant, so users can say something like "Hey Google, order a pizza on ExampleApp" you'll need App Actions. You use [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) to offer deeper voice control of your apps to users by enabling them to use their voice to perform specific tasks in your app. Check out the [How App Actions work section](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview#how_app_actions_work) in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) for details on how it works.